How to set the mixed potential of buckhaming and Morse in lammps?(windows10
This is the code I tried:
log                         log.txt
units               metal
dimension           3
boundary                    p p p
atom_style          charge

read_data               H0.6.data

# atom charges
set type 1 charge 0.6 # H
set type 2 charge 1.2 # Ca
set type 3 charge 2.4 # Si
set type 4 charge -1.2 #O


group H type 1
group Ca type 2
group Si type 3
group O type 4

          
################################################################## 
pair_style                         hybrid/overlay buck/coul/long 10.0 10.0  morse 2.5 
pair_style          buck/coul/long 10.0 10.0          
kspace_style        ewald 1.0e-5

pair_coeff      1 4  morse 7.0525 0.19 0.9485
pair_coeff      2 4  buck/coul/long 7747.1834 0.252623 93.109
pair_coeff      3 4  buck/coul/long 13702.905 0.193817 54.681
pair_coeff      4 4  buck/coul/long 1844.7458 0.343645 192.58

This is an error in picture.
I am a rookie, not yet started, no one to teach me, please help set a buckhaming and Morse potential mixed potential template, thank you!
